# How to make a UserControl remove itself at runtime (in WPF)?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dispose

I have made a `userControl` consisting a few labels and checkboxes and an "x" button for removing itself when clicked.

Considering that in my WPF application, the user can dynamically put as many of this `userControl` at runtime as he wants, **AND** that none of them will have a `name` attribute to address to, how exactly is it possible to remove a `UserControl` from the application, by clicking on it's -child- button "x" (i.e. inside the event handler of it's "x" button)  ???

---

I've already looked a thousand places and found these particular two lines of code which **DID'NT WORK** :

```
((Grid)button.Parent).Children.Remove(this);
((Button)control.Parent).Content = null;
```

Comment: Why didn't `.Remove(this)` work? Did you get an exception?

Comment: I don't know why. Actually I couldn't trace the codes related to my UserControl, cuz it's a DLL file.
But as far as I know, it might have not been able to find the item through the hierarchy ... :/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In case your control has been added to any kind of container control (i.e. a class derived from Panel) the following should work:

```
((Panel)this.Parent).Children.Remove(this);
```